# itertools.tee on a coroutine?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, coroutine, tee

I have a tree structure of objects. I need to iterate over all the items ("values") in the leaves. For this I'm currently using generator methods as illustrated below:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [Leaf(1), Leaf(2), Leaf(3)]

    def values(self):
        for item in self.items:
            for value in item.values():
                yield value

class Leaf(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def values(self):
        for i in range(2):
            yield self.value

n = Node()
for value in n.values():
    print(value)
```

This prints:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Now, the values returned by a `Leaf` will depend on an external parameter. I was thinking of employing coroutines to be able to pass this parameter down to the leaf nodes:

```
import itertools

class Node2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [Leaf2(1), Leaf2(2), Leaf2(3)]

    def values(self):
        parameter = yield
        for item in self.items:
            item_values = item.values()
            next(item_values)    # advance to first yield
            try:
                while True:
                    parameter = (yield item_values.send(parameter))
            except StopIteration:
                pass

class Leaf2(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def values(self):
        parameter = yield
        try:
            for i in range(2):
                parameter = (yield '{}{}'.format(self.value, parameter))
        except StopIteration:
            pass

n2 = Node2()
values2 = n2.values()
next(values2)    # advance to first yield

try:
    for i in itertools.count(ord('A')):
        print(values2.send(chr(i)))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

This code is far from pretty, but it works. It prints:

```
1A
1B
2C
2D
3E
3F
```

There's a problem with this solution though. I was using `itertools.tee` (and `chain`) extensively to easily save the state of the iterator in case I needed to backtrack. I was hoping these would work on coroutines as well, but alas, no such luck.

Some alternative solutions I'm considering at the moment:

- have the generators yield functions (closures) that accept the external parameter
- write custom classes to emulate coroutines with capabilities for saving state

The first option seems the most attractive. But perhaps there are better options?

---

Some context: I'm using this construct in [RinohType](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype) where the tree is formed by `MixedStyledText` (node) and `SingleStyledText` (leaf) objects. The `spans()` methods yield `SingleStyledText` instances. The latter can be dependent on external parameters. For example, the page number they are being rendered to. These are currently treated as a special case.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I'm developing on Python 3.4, but will probably backport to 2.7 eventually (single codebase for 2.7 and 3.x). Any particular reason you ask?

Comment: Sounds like a place where the visitor pattern could be applied - have you considered that?

Answer (score 1):

To the extent possible, I like to make functions return simple data structures. In this case,

- I'd make each node yield a simple dictionary (or, in `RinohType`'s case, a `SingleStyledTextConfig` object or `namedtuple`). This implementation will play nicely with `itertools`, as before, since it just transforms data into other data.
- I'd transform this collection of objects to account for external parameters (like the page number).
- Finally, I'd use the collection of configuration data to actually create the output (in `RinohType`'s case, the `SingleStyledText` object).

At a higher level: your proposed solution (as I understand your simplified version) is **trying to do too much stuff at the same time**. It's trying to configure object creation, tweak that configuration, and create objects based on *that* configuration all in one step. Your implementation will be simpler, play nicer with `itertools`, and be easier to test if you separate these concerns.

For a more detailed treatment of this kind of thinking, see [Gary Bernhardt's *Boundaries* talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) and [Brandon Rhodes' talk on the Clean Architecture in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJtef410XaM) (and of course the resources they mention in the talks).

Answer (score 0):

This is a start on the second option

```
from types import GeneratorType

def gen_wrapper(func):
    def _inner(*args):
        try:
            if args:
                if isinstance(args[0], GeneratorType):
                    func.gen = getattr(func, 'gen', args[0])

                func.recall = next(func.gen)

            try:
                return func.recall
            except AttributeError:
                func.recall = next(func.gen)
                return func.recall 

        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return _inner

@gen_wrapper
def Gen_recall(*args):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly.
Is it needed for Leaf2 to do the calculations?
If not, then you can do:

```
import itertools

class Node2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [Leaf2(1), Leaf2(2), Leaf2(3)]

    def values(self):
        for item in self.items:
            for value in item.values():
                yield value

class Leaf2(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def values(self):
        for i in range(2):
            yield self.value

def process(i, parameter):
    return '{}{}'.format(i, parameter)

n = Node2()
for value, parameter in zip(n.values(), itertools.count(ord('A'))):
    print(process(value, chr(parameter)))
```

If it's really important that Leaf2 does the processing, you could do

```
class Leaf2:
    def values(self):
        for i in range(2):
            yield self

def process(self, parameter):
    pass
```

So that in the main you can do

```
n = Node2()
for node, parameter in zip(n.values(), itertools.count(ord('A'))):
    print(node.process(chr(parameter)))
```